# Integral ambiguity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, vectors, integration, calculus

I'm a bit confused with some notation I encounter in physics calculus. Consider this:
[image]

Taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)). 
Integration operates on functions, correct? What does it mean to integrate $\frac{d{\bf p}}{dt} dt$? Could someone point me to some reading about the manipulation of Leibniz notation?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the answer is in Wikipedia. $F = \frac{dp}{dt}$ relates force to momentum.

Comment: Ok, but is that the net force or the change in momentum that a single force imparts? How do we factor that change in? I apologize if I'm not making much sense; I'm struggling with some intuition here.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): It seems the question essentially is _How to interpret vector-valued integration formulas?_

Comment: @RustyDoornobs: I would think it's the total change in momentum - note the integral. But if QMechanic is right, and the question is about vectors, then this would be wrong.

Comment: OK, I believe one source of confusion for me was not realizing that NET FORCE = dp/dt, not just a single force. Generally, I see a lot of manipulation with differentials in physics. Is there something I could read to better understand this? I think that there is a weakness in my calculus intuition in this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it mean to integrate $\frac{d\mathbf p}{dt}dt$?

First, and in scalar form, recall from elementary calculus that

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx = x_2 - x_1 $$

Second, recall that

$$f(x + dx) = f(x) + f'(x)dx$$

where

$$f'(x) = \frac{df(x)}{dx} $$

Denoting the differential of $f$ as

$$df = f(x + dx) - f(x)$$

we have

$$df = f'(x)dx$$

Since

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f'(x)dx = f(x_2) - f(x_1) = f_2 - f_1$$

it follows that

$$\int_{f_1}^{f_2} df = f_2 - f_1 = f(x_2) - f(x_1) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f'(x)dx$$

Answer (score 1):

While in some contexts,

$$
\frac{d\textbf{p}}{dt}dt = d\textbf{p}
$$

is correct and is mathematically rigorous, there is a straightforward way to derive impulse as the change in momentum. Consider a function $f(x)$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f \in C^1$. Suppose its derivative is $g = f'(x)$.  We can consider integrating $g(x)$ over some interval $I = [x_i, x_f] \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ such that

$$
\int_I g(t)dt = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}g(t)dt = f(x_2) - f(x_1),
$$

by the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). We can apply this result to momentum to get your result. Consider that the momentum $\textbf{p}(t)$ of a particle is simply a function $\textbf{p}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$. The impulse is defined as the *net external force* $\textbf{F}_{ext}(t)$ that a particle experiences over some time interval $I = [t_1, t_2]$, or

$$\textbf{J} \equiv \int_I \textbf{F}(t)dt,$$

where the "ext" has been dropped for brevity. (It is still understood that it represents the net external force.) By definition, $\textbf{F}(t) \equiv \textbf{p}'(t),$ so we can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to obtain the desired result:

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \textbf{F}(t)dt = \textbf{p}(t_2) - \textbf{p}(t_1) = \Delta \textbf{p}.$$

Comment: Yes, I understand from the second line and below in the image. My confusion lies in the logic made to go from the first line to the second line.

Comment: Edited to show how the fundamental theorem of calculus is used to derive the result.

Comment: No, $(dp/dt)dt=dp$ is not an abuse of notation. In this notation, $dp$ and $dt$ can be interpreted as infinitesimal numbers. That's how Leibniz interpreted them, and that interpretation has rigorous logical support in non-standard analysis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis

Comment: One can also write it like $dp = (\partial p/\partial t) \, dt$, which is true in a well-defined way when viewed as 1-form, using only standard calculus.

Answer (score 0):

> Integration operates on functions, correct?

No. Integration dates back to ca. 1670. The notion of a function gradually evolved and didn't get put into its modern form until ca. 1830. Let's look at your expression

$$ \int_{p_1}^{p_2} dp .$$

This is Leibniz's notation, and what he means by it is a sum of infinitely many terms $dp$. Each of these terms is an infinitesimal change in the variable $p$, which doesn't have to be a function of anything.

There is a lot of confusion about the way physicists and engineers use differentials, because there was a period ca. 1880-1960 when it was believed that they were logically suspect and the only correct way to understand calculus was in terms of limits. [Non-standard analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis) cleared up this confusion and showed that infinitesimals were not logically problematic. A nice book at the freshman calc level that explains the modern way of looking at this is Keisler, https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html , which is free online.

Comment: So, what does it mean when we integrate dy/dx, for example? The following I understand: integrating dx results in one, big delta x. That makes sense intuitively to me since we are adding up many infinitesimal changes to determine the total change. However, often I hear that we integrate the 'derivative'. If the derivative is dy/dx, how do we integrate that? We just tack on a dx so the dx's cancel out? There is my confusion. 
By the way, this is the second time I've been linked to that book. I'll definitely give it a good look.
Thanks for your reply.